# How to make multiple buttons open in second activity?

Tags: java, android

I was working on a different code site before Android studio, and how they made buttons in a second activity open was different than here. So far I have my second activity button and it opens..

My **fifthactivity.java** is below

```
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifth_layout);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FifthActivity.this, AmazonActivity.class);
            FifthActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
          }
      });
   }
}
```

I understand I need to make a new .java and a new layout to direct the button, I just need help with the code to put into my fifth activity.java

Below is my layout for the other button that i need to open.

```
<Button
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PlayStation"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/playstation"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/playstation"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:id="@+id/button5" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem. Do you want to open another activity from your current one?

Comment: @AmandaBrito I Would Like to open a new activity from another button in my fifthactivity.java I already have a button that opens for "Amazon" but i have another button that I would like to open.

Comment: So, from what I understood you want to have several buttons within the same layout to open multiple screens? You may change your layout to have a container such as a RelativeLayout, and put as many buttons as you want. On your activity you can access these buttons and open the screens you want, just like you did for the one posted above. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Button button;
    Button anotherButton;   // the second button OP required

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fifth_layout);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        anotherButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FifthActivity.this, AmazonActivity.class);
                FifthActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
              }
          });

        /* new button to open a new activity */
        anotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating the intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(FifthActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
                // starting activity with the created intent
                startActivity(intent);
              }
          });
       }
    }
```

Comment: Something like this, @Porzingis

Answer (score 0):

Add new Button to your xml file and style it how do you like and add new id like
`android:id="@+id/button6"` :

```
<Button
tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="PlayStation"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/playstation"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/playstation"
android:layout_weight="0.07"
android:textSize="35sp"
android:id="@+id/button5" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button6"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="SomeText"
android:textSize="35sp" />
```

In your **fifthactivity.java** add new Button:

```
Button button, button2;
```

and, like your previous button, add click listener to that button. Create new Java class with its own layout and open it thru `Intent` with that button.